# How do I implement an item that can hold other items?

Tags: unity, rpg, inventory

I'm attempting to implement a "storage item" into my game. But I'm having trouble planning out how it would work. I already have an inventory system made, but this storage item is giving me trouble.

The storage item basically acts as a pouch you hold in your inventory, like a coin purse that holds money, or a potion sack that holds your potions.

So far I have the following:

```
public class Inventory{
    public ItemStack[] inventory;
}
public class ItemStack{
    public Item item;
    public int amount;
}
public abstract class StorageItem : Item{
    public Item storedItem;    //Specific Item the StorageItem can contain.
    public int storedMax;      //Maximum amount the StorageItem can contain
    //StorageItem's Item.maxStack = 1; Should never be stackeable, but should hold stacks of storedItem
}
public abstract class Item{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public int maxStack;
}
```

Does anyone have an idea how they would get `ItemStack` and `StorageItem` to work together in an inventory system?

Example:
If I wanted to add a health potion, my inventory would search through, find all existing stacks, (including storage items holding health potions), and attempt to fill them.
But the `ItemStac` that holds the `StorageItem` already has an amount, which corresponds to the actual `StorageItem` rather than the item it stores. And since `StorageItem` should never be stack on itself (but stacks other items in itself), it is always 'full'.

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking about this a little to much. You really only need 2 things:
An array for inventory, and items to put in the array.

```
Object[] inventory;

public abstract class item{
    public int id
    public string name;
    public int maxStack;
    public int amount;
}
//down the road to use this:
item x = new item(id, name, maxstack, 1);
inventory.push(x);

//inventory[0] is now x with 1 of them stored
int y = inventory[0].amount; //y = 1
Debug.Log(y); //logs 1
inventory.RemoveAt(inventory[0]);
```

This is a very simple way to use it, but might not be copy pastable. The real theory here is to create an array for the player that is an inventory. Then create an item to put into inventory(needs to know how many of itself are in the stack) and push them onto the array.

EDIT: saw your comment on another post. If the case is that you want to change how many max stacks you can have it's EASY. Simply:

```
newMax = 50000;
inventory[0].maxStack = newMax;
//as long as you setup your permissions or mutators correctly this will work
```

Now if you're meaning to start storing stacks of things in an inventory that's easy as well with just a two dimensional array by creating a sub inventory(an object with an array in it)

```
public abstract class Bag = {
    public object[] contents;
    public int maxObjects;
    public function addTo(item item){
        if(contents.Length < maxObjects){
            contents.push(item);
        }
    }
}

//put that bag into inventory
inventory.push(new Bag(maxObjects)); //bag is now in inventory at [0]
//the constructor should know how to handle creating an empty array

inventory[0].addTo(Item);
```

So there are a couple of examples that should help you think about this in a different way.

Comment: While this is a very simple, and undoubtedly effective way to manage an Inventory, I already have an Inventory System working. What I truly wanted was to "Put Items into another Item". ex: Coins into a Coin Pouch. Potions into a Potion Sack. Or in a more general sense: Items into an ItemBag

Comment: @Kadenaa then you'll like my edit. It goes over doing an item bag with a max storage too

Comment: Yes, that last example with the abstract Bag class is very much like what I'm shooting for. Thank you very much for your help and for giving me another way to think about the problem :)

Comment: @Kadenaa No problem. Game design is more than just coding, it's a way of thinking. And I also hope you're coding in C# because that's why I did my code in XD

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the inventory to have a specific layout (like 2D grid or something else) you can just have a `HashSet<ItemStack>`.

[HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can extend your class `Inventory` to have methods such as `Add` or `Remove` to find an item of the same class already stored, and increment or decrease the amount of items in stack

A possible solution could be to implement [IEqualityComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) in ItemStack so you can't have duplicates.

Comment: The inventory array is set as a single-dimension array, but is used as a multi-tiled inventory. So upon construction they would type
new Inventory(width, height);
to get the ItemStack at x, y. All I'd have to do it take y * x + x, and that would be the index.

I'm fine with how my inventory architecture is right now, just looking to see how to implement StorageItem with ItemStack.

Comment: Then I don't see the point. An inventory system can be done with three classes: a container (Inventory in your code), Items to be contained (Item in your code, abstract), and finally (and not really needed) a stack of items to be held in one cell of inventory (ItemStack).

Comment: Alright, perhaps I wasn't too clear about what I'm looking for. I already have an Inventory System working.
Imagine this though, I have a class Gold Coin : Item. Gold Coin usually has a max stack of 1000, but I want to create a Storage Item Large Coin Pouch : StorageItem which can hold 50000 Gold Coins.

Answer (score 0):

After gathering different Ideas from multiple sources, I think I've found what I'm really looking for. For those who come along and ask the same question I'll post what I've found adequate here.

I've decided to create a new class called ItemContainer, which my StorageItem, and Inventory will inherit from. Thusly making my StorageItem a mini-inventory.

ItemContainer will have methods like addStack, removeStack, etc. But if I want to add an Item to a StorageItem, I'd simply have to check if the StorageItem holds the Item I want to add, and then call the StorageItem's ItemContainer to add the item to it. Effectively putting Items into another Item.

Answer (score 0):

*While this is a very simple, and undoubtedly effective way to manage an Inventory, I already have an Inventory System working. What I truly wanted was to "Put Items into another Item". ex: Coins into a Coin Pouch. Potions into a Potion Sack. Or in a more general sense: Items into an ItemBag*

Ultima Online's solution uses containers inside containers (backpacks, bags, crates...).

Just let your class `Inventory` extend `Item`.